# Django channels error loading javascript wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-channels

channels. So far i have successfully ran the server ,as this appeared in my cmd prompt:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 21, 2020 - 17:43:42
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'crm.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.4.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

however im facing with this error within my console :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)websocketbridge.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: channels is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):353)
```

Here is my code.

in my settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["0.0.0.0","127.0.0.1"]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'channels',
.....
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crm.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'crm.routing.application'
```

in my routers.py:

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter , URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from rnd.consumers import EchoConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
            path("ws/",EchoConsumer)
        ])
    })
```

In my consumers.py:

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
```

class EchoConsumer(AsyncConsumer):

```
async def websocket_connect(self,event):
    await self.send({
            "type" : "websocket.accept"
        })

async def websocket_receive(self,event):
    await self.send({
            "type" : "websocket.send",
            "text" : event["text"]
        })
```

in my html:

```
<script src="{% static '/channels/js/websocketbridge.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    const webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
    webSocketBridge.connect('/ws/');
    webSocketBridge.listen(function(action,stream){
      console.log("RESPONSE:",action,stream);
    })
    document.ws = webSocketBridge; 
  })
</script>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The websocketbridge is not supported for channels >= v2

There are a few libs that sit onto of channels v2 that attempt to bring back some of this functionality.

- https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework
- https://github.com/theY4Kman/dcrf-client

(disclaimer I am the developer of the `djangochannelsrestframework` package)

alternatively you can use the WS directly through the browsers api.